# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured. SpringBott 3.1.0

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, couchbase, spring-boot-starter

I have a project with these dependencies:

```
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "3.1.0"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase"
    implementation platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2022.0.2")
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.1.0'
```

in my application.yml file, I am giving couchbase url like this:

```
spring:
  couchbase:
    connection-string:
```

And I am getting this error:

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

    Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (the profiles local are currently active).
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Would you please show the actual connection string/url attribute value (or at least a redacted version of it)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to use JPA or Couchbase? It sounds like you're supplying a couchbase url to JPA.
There is a spring-data-couchbae example at https://github.com/couchbaselabs/try-cb-spring

And more at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/